# Symfony2 Rookie: how to manipulate header content

Tags: controller, symfony

I have an action, that should return not a normal page, but a torrent file.

So after some work and manipulation, something like this should be done at the end.

```
    header('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$torrent->filename.'"');
    echo (TrackerHelper::bencode($dict));
    exit;
```

When I do this I get

> This webpage is not found

even if I do this at end of the action, also page not found.

```
    header('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$torrent->filename.'"');
    //echo (TrackerHelper::bencode($dict));
    //exit;
    return new Response(TrackerHelper::bencode($dict));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the headers in the response. The constructor signature for the response object is as follow:

```
public function __construct($content = '', $status = 200, $headers = array())
```

so you can say something like:

```
return new Response(TrackerHelper::bencode($dict), 200, array(
  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-bittorrent', 
  [...]
);
```

Anyway the page not found message would suggest you are making some other mistake, check your routing and your controller!

Answer (score 0):

try this variation:

```
$response = new Response(TrackerHelper::bencode($dict));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-bittorrent');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$torrent->filename.'"');

return $response;
```